# How can I attach Velcro to a fly screen?

Tags: adhesive, screens

I bought some screens and some velcro strips (which came already with adhesive) and set up some fly screens. But after some time the screens started to unglue from the velcro, the adhesive was not strong enough or there was not enough surface to it to hold,

I want any suggestion to fix the screen to the velcro, some kind of glue/adhesive. I tried super glue and hot glue but neither worked. I'm almost considering sewing it or putting it in a frame (which was not the original idea)

Here's the screen I have:

[image: screens]

Comment: Buy better glue and use more of it.

Comment: Make a fold and sew it.

Answer (score 3):

What about velcroing through the screen, then sticking another piece on the back, basically making a velcro frame around the screen? This is hard to explain, here's a diagram:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
LLLLLLLLLL
SSSSSSSSSS
HHHHHHHHHH
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAA
LLLLLLLLLL

HHHHHHHHHH
AAAAAAAAAA
FFFFFFFFFF
```

The first 2 rows (AL) are one piece of velcro, loop side, with the adhesive away from the screen (leave the backing on this adhesive).

Next row is the screen (S)

Next 2 rows (HA) are another piece of velcro, hook side, again with adhesive away from the screen (backing removed from this piece).

Next 2 rows (AL) are another piece, loop side, adhesive against the previous piece so they stick back-to-back

Everything above here is on the screen (removable). Everything below is fixed to the wall.

The next 2 rows (HA) are the velcro stuck to the frame, and finally the F is the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Just stick the hook side of the velcro to the window frames then press the netting onto the hooks directly

Answer (score -1):

Just buy a better glue it may seem simple but it really works

Comment: Any recommendation for the *type* of glue to use?